# Fitting a curve to the edge of a distribution

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, outliers

I need to be able to find outliers in my data. I thought it best to test for this using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test.

I have over 800,000 points so I wanted a way to filter the data first to only test those that are on the edge of my sample. By eye I can fit an exponential decay (red line) but I was wondering if there was a statistical way to determine the parameters for my exponential.

[image]

Comment: You will find it illuminating to plot these *bivariate* data on log-log axes.  (To include the zero values you will need to add a small constant to all values first.)  Among other things, you will find that the exponential decay is not quite right; the relationship may be better approximated with a power law.

Comment: +1 whuber. @xboxrob: Aren't you, by fitting a curve, already making assumptions about what might be an outlier? I'm not sure.

Comment: Might help if you say *why* you need to find outliers. By eye, I wouldn't say there are any particularly severe outliers, considering the size of the data set. The only obvious anomaly is the little line of values with y=0 for x=1,2,3,4.. with a gap just above it.

Comment: Yes, this is a weird one:  if your points are random, their boundary is not a density function... There is a large literature on non-parametric support estimation, see e.g. [Devroye 1980](www.jstor.org/stable/2100656) or [Tsybakov 1997](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.aos/1069362732).

Comment: xboxrob, it is unclear what you are asking for, and consequently the replies you are getting may or may not be applicable; at any rate, future readers will not be able to gauge whether they are appropriate solutions.  The K-S test does not seem applicable--you display bivariate data and it's for univariate data only--and finding outliers does not seem related to your red curve.  What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Hi all,

Firstly thank you for your responses. The y-axis is a measurement of difference between two measurements. The x-axis is the minimum value of the two measurements. As you have noted this is univariate data and hence when x is small there is much larger differences by random chance.

The idea therefore is that points that are far away from the edge of the distribution (roughly the red line) are actually important values as the difference between the two measurements should be more believable

Comment: On the contrary, I noted these are **bivariate** data, as your description confirms.  It is really strange that the variance of the measurements would *increase* as the measurements themselves decrease.  This suggests that both $x$ and $y$ are actually differences relative to a large value (perhaps around $100$ or so).  It would be more productive and informative to work with the original $(x,y)$ data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhabs [nonlinear Quantile Regression](http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~roger/research/rq/QReco.pdf)?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to look for "extreme value" theory and distributions.

If you are using R do the following:

install.packages("texmex", dep=T)

then type following in the

help(package=texmex)

A